# finding difference in two columns of a spread sheet?

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

lets say I have 3 columns

```
A   B   C
1   2   
2   3
4   5
```

and i will go on entering numbers in A and B, in C I need to have the difference between col B and col A, can I write a single formula for the entire column? what is the formula if so? this is my first encounter with formulas in spreadsheets so excuse the mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: So you want column **C** to show 1, 3, 4, 5 because 2 is not a difference??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is located in A1:B4, in C2 put :

```
=ABS(A2-B2)
```

and drag the cell downwards.

Please share if it works/understandable/not. ( :